# MongoDB data modelling and schema

Tags: database, mongodb, schema

I am writing an application which has the following DB structure.

A topic with multiple sub-topics which are key-pair mappings. Since I need highly scalable and highly responsive Db, I moved to NOSQL, document-based MongoDB. I am not entirely sure about the data schema and modelling design, even though it is schema-less.

**Here are the following implementations I thought of -**

a) multiple Database for topics - multiple collections of sub-topics with a simple key-value pair schema.

b) 1 Database for application - all key-pair values of sub-topics in one collection. Maybe a key "type" to identify the sub-topics.

c) 1 Database for application - multiple collections for topics - and their respective key-value pairs as schemas.

d) multiple Database for topics - 1 collection in each database where key-value pairs are dumped with "type" key in schema when necessary.

Basically, yes, A many-many, 1-many, many-1, 1-1 structures.

It would be great for someone to throw some light on the schema that I must proceed with and reasons for the same.

**More details -**
1) Access-lookup -> I only need to lookup by keys, so yes indexing will be done. if a schema with "type" key, will go ahead with compound indexing.
2) Quantity - Like I said, this will be highly scalable and new keys in terms of millions will be added weekly.

I have gone through multiple source of good practices and other schema-design questions, but, there wasn't enough light shed on when to choose which. Other questions here in StackOverflow also turned out to be very different.

Comment: The reason for other answers to be different is because there is no silver bullet for all cases. Have a read https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 for inspiration. Prototype the db with [mgenerate](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs), benchmark typical queries, adjust the schema, play with indexes, repeat until you're happy with the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the blog post and went through the options available for embedding and normalization. But, I am stuck at a more fundamental level, I believe. Collections or databases. Which is a more scalable options. Is partitioning of one collection better than multiple collections?

Comment: Anything stops you to test it and pick the best one? Nobody knows your data better then you, and the answer totally depends on data itself, its size and intended usage.